# Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/perform_compile' when running ng-packagr

Tags: npm, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I have a new install of windows and I'm trying to run ng-packagr for the first time.

I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/perform_compile'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ts\tsconfig.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I did install the angular CLI by running

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

It's running v6.0.8

My ng-package.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "index.ts",
        "externals": {
            "moment": "moment"
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey recently solved a similar problem you can try following:

1. Install latest node.js (Uninstall the previous version)
2. Install the latest angular-cli globally

   ```
   npm uninstall -g angular-cli
   npm cache clean or npm cache verify (if npm > 5)
   npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
   ```
3. Create a new project with angular-cli
   `ng new projectname`
4. Copy your files (modules, component, directive etc.) into newly created project from your old one
5. Install ng-packagr
   `npm i ng-packagr`
6. Edit your `package.json` (root project)

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
   }
   ```

   Remove dependencies or move all to peerDependencies since you are going to create a feature module
7. `ng-package.json` (may be different in your case but you can try this)

   ```json
   {
     "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
     "lib": {
       "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
     }
   }
   ```
8. `public_api.ts` (update relative path to your module)

   ```
   export * from './src/app/modules/yourmodulename/yourmodulename.module
   ```

And that's it now you can run `npm run packagr` it should work and generate dist folder.

You can publish on npmjs using `npm publish dist`

That's how I resolved it.

Comment: Yeah,.I figured out you have to install ng-packagr v1.x or it won't work.